# How do I work with HTML5 android apps in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, html

I'm trying to port a HTML5 app to android and I'm doing it in Eclipse. The "android" (java) part is no problem, Eclipse is great. When I open the HTML part though, Eclipse is not so great. Since it's an android project it doesn't seem to recognize html, css or javascript files. My solution so far is to have Eclipse open for the java parts of the project and then I imported the HTML content that I have in my assets folder into a new HTML5 project in to NetBeans and edit it from there.

This is a bit annoying though as I have to have two IDE´s open at the same time and switch between them.

Is there a setting in, or plugin to, Eclipse that allows for android projects to recognize HTML5 documents and get full support to edit them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to upgrade your version of eclipse. The newest version of Helios should have it built in. Or depending on your version you may need to add support. (http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/working-with-html5-in-eclipse-juno.html#fbid=URJEyY5-4N1)

Install New Software -> Web, XML and Java EE development -> Web Page Editor

Take a look here to add support http://lizusefulstuff.blogspot.kr/2012/07/how-to-add-html-editor-for-eclipse.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well, almost. I went to **"Install New Software => Web, XML and Java EE and OSGi Development"** and installed **"Eclipse Web Developer Tools"** and **"Eclipse Javascript Development Tools"** and now I can choose open with the HTML or Javascript editor. I'm running Kepler btw.

Answer (score 1):

Aptana has a very nice HTML editor, and can be installed as a plugin in your existing Eclipse configuration, although it might be a bit overkill to install it just for the HTML editor.

Comment: This is a bit too much. I just wanted to be able to open the files with any kind of intellisense or at least highlighting support. The Aptana plugin is nice though.

Answer (score 0):

instal plugin in eclipse "aptana". Solution For Your Problem
http://update1.aptana.org/studio/3.2/024747/index.html